# Video player of flutter has stuttering

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, exoplayer, flutter-video-player

I use [video_player(2.6.1)](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player).
The video display stutters on my device so that the sound plays earlier than the picture.

Flutter version is 3.7.9.
Android SDK version 33.0.0

The device information is as follows:
Samsung GalaxyA01/
Android version 12/
Memory 2G/
Memory available 533 MB/

[Sample](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12783325/181383492-971a1c9d-30d4-43f2-a209-39a158b231fd.mov)

I tried on other devices, it worked.